# Как центрировать кнопку "Читать далее.." c градиентом на ВСЮ ширину блока?

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гуру.

Я упростил как смог код с ранее подготовленного шаблона страницы http://rgho.st/private/8QFjYQG5D/ad162ebcaaf898efa06aa7d35129dcac , дабы вписать его тут.

```css
.ta,
.ta2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
}
.read-next2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  position: static;
  bottom-top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))
}
```

```html
<aside class="widget popular-posts">
  <p class="widget-title">Главные статьи</p>

  <div style="height:100%">
    <div class="ta2" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 1 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 2 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 3 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 4 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 5 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 6 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 7 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 8 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 9 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 10 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="read-next2"><a class="read-next22" href="#">Читать далее...</a>
    </div>
  </div>


</aside>
```

Как центрировать кнопку "Читать далее.." c градиентом на **всю** ширину блока, а также прописать небольшой отступ сверху для кнопки относительно контента. Сам блок центрировать не надо - это резиновый сайдбар со списком статей.

А вот как это всё выглядит сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не вебмастер и в основном я черпаю примеры реализации того или иного дизайнерского решения с других ресурсов, но таких конструкций я встречал мало, и попытки адаптации вы можете сейчас наблюдать :-( Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам такой вариант нужен? (добавил ширину блоку в html для наглядности; меняя `margin-top` и `height` у `.read-text2` вы можете добиться нужного вам отображения)

```css
.ta,
.ta2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
}
li {
  height: 20px;
}
.read-next2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  margin-top: -25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.read-next22 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<aside class="widget popular-posts">
  <p class="widget-title">Главные статьи</p>

  <div style="height:100%; width: 300px;background:#FFF;">
    <div class="ta2" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 1 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 2 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 3 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 4 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 5 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 6 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 7 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 8 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 9 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>

        <li>
          <a title="" href=""></a>
          <a title="" href="">Главная статья 10 - в ней то-то.</a> 
        </li>


      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="read-next2">
    </div>
    <a class="read-next22" href="#">Читать далее...</a>
  </div>


</aside>
```

Comment: К сожалению нет. Переход должен быть плавным, чтобы было понятно даже на самом плохом мониторе, который не отображает половину оттенков. А ещё отступ должен быть. Вот эта картинка визуально показывает как должно быть http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0211/40/33c982e6a5434831aad75f386ae71540.png

Comment: Внес правки и пояснительный комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что откликнулись, я внёс соответствующие правки в тестовый шаблон и кнопка "Читать далее.." стала залезать на текст, а также последний пункт так и продолжал оставаться засвеченным при полном раскрытии списка, создавая впечатление что там ещё что-то есть. Я залил изначальный шаблон сайта на сервис тестирования https://jsfiddle.net/5h0gfo6c/1/ может это прояснит ситуацию.

Comment: Внес правки в ваш фиддл https://jsfiddle.net/5h0gfo6c/2/

Comment: Не сочтите за наглость, но хотелось бы столь же широкий переход (градиент), как в изначальном варианте. Чтобы плавно перекрывало полторы строки (изначальный вариант), а не четверть строки (как сейчас).  Просто на мониторах с плохими TN матрицами столь короткий градиент вообще не будет заметен, проверено :-(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5h0gfo6c/3/ ?

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы меня очень выручили! Теперь красота :-)